# How to distinguish onKeyDown from the onClick event (input=“radio”)

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, keyboard-events, onkeydown

how in the "onClick" function, check if the click was triggered by an onClick event - by mouse or event triggered by the keyboard?

```
const onClick = () => {
 console.log("onClick");
}

const onKeyDown = (e) => {
 console.log("onKeyDown");
}
const Root = () => (
 <div>
  <input type="radio" id="Name" name="contact" onClick={onClick} 
   onKeyDown={onKeyDown}/>
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input type="radio" id="Email" name="contact" onClick={onClick} 
   onKeyDown={onKeyDown}/>
  <label for="Email">Email</label>
 </div>
)
```

When I click the down or up arrow (I change the radio options with the keyboard) the onKeyDown and onClick event is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the event has `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` coordinates:

```
if (e.type === 'click' && e.pageX !== 0 && e.pageY !== 0)
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.type === 'click' && e.pageX !== 0 && e.pageY !== 0) {
      console.log(e.type);
    }
  });

  elem.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    console.log(e.type);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="Name" name="contact" />
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input type="radio" id="Email" name="contact" />
  <label for="Email">Email</label>
</div>
```

Comment: e.clientX and e.clientY doesn't work on the browser IE and EDGE ;/

Answer (score 0):

As name specifies of these functions. onKeyDown is triggered when a user press keyboard key. and 
onClick triggers when a user click on field by mean of mouse or any other device.

Answer (score 0):

`event.type` will give the name of the event

```js
document.getElementById('dempRadio').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type)
})

document.getElementById('dempRadio').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type)
})
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="dempRadio"> Test
```

Comment: OnKeyDown event call function onKeyDown and onClick:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdzgvL